# How to parse data into proper json in python and remove slashes

Tags: python, arrays, json

I am getting this as my response

```
b'{"userdetails":[["{\\”user_id\\":[\\”54562af66ffd\\"],\\”user_name\\":[\\"bewwrking\\"],\\”room\\":[\\"31\\”]}'
```

I want to convert it into proper json without any double slashes.

Is there any buildin function for that or i need to do string replace

Comment: Is this exact copy/paste of the value? Because I can see two different types of apostrophes: " (0x22) and ” (0x201d)

Comment: @Marek , i first pasted in some text editor that chnaged apostrophes but data is same

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over how it is being sent, I would recommend doing to_string on any relevant field/keys that you are sending as json. I had some weird json responses before sanitizing the input to json_dump.

Answer (score -1):

remove the leading b and run replace as below.

```
s = '{"userdetails":[["{\\"user_id\\":[\\"54562af66ffd\\"],\\"user_name\\":[\\"bewwrking\\"],\\"room\\":[\\"31\\"]}'
```

s = s.replace('\','')

```
print(s)

{"userdetails":[["{"user_id":["54562af66ffd"],"user_name":["bewwrking"],"room":["31"]}
```